# Script for row-banding alternating every nth rows

Tags: google-apps-script, background-color, alternating

I am looking for a google apps script that will alternate row banding color every nth rows (in my case it will be every 7), accounting for a one row header.
I specifically want to use a script so that I can add and delete sets of 7 rows and automatically keep the banding on edit.
Thanks!
Richard

I managed to get alternating rows by myself but could not achieve multiples.

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `I specifically want to use a script so that I can add and delete sets of 7 rows and automatically keep the banding on edit.`. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: You might want to try webapps.stackexchange.com as well. This problem is not hard, but probably no one wants to learn that API.